# L10N process for an global application

Tags: localization, internationalization

Today I need some help to implement a process to keep the multilingual versions of our application up to date.

1) Our current context:

We work on a big application which is translated in english and french.
Our application is coded in angularjs. (We use [angular-localization](https://github.com/doshprompt/angular-localization) for the translation.)

We have one json per language which contain all the key:translation of the application.

We work with a git repository. New features are coded in new branches and bug fixes in a develop branch. When we put new features or bugs fix on production we just merge this branch on a master one that we release on production.

2) How we work:

We are very flexible and reactive so we usually have a bug fix or small feature release on production every day. 
Major new features are released on production after they passed our QA cycle.

3) What we need:

When changes include language modifications, we need to have a process to perform the multiple translations. The first idea is to send the json to our translators every time we need a new release. The problem with this solution is that we want to keep our flexibility and not be tied up to response time of our translators. The more languages we have, the more problematic this issue will become.

We actually need some help to implement a process that will preserve the flexibility of releasing when we need to and and that will propagate multiple translations as fast as possible.

Our process management needs to include:

- every day release without L10N for important bugs
- translation before release minors bugs fix
- translation before release new features
- have easy access to content requiring a translation in order to sent this information to our translators
- have a script that insert translated content in the json files of the application

If someone already had to think about a similar process I appreciate your help.

Comment: It is more like Localization process than I18n process. Anyways, such information costs. I doubt anyone will help you design L10n process without any fee. Although you can find something in my answers, which will allow for designing such a process. To be honest, the best what you can do is to contact experienced Translation Service Provider and talk to them. They will tell you how to prepare files for translation and what are minimum response times (and translator throughput). But again, this will cost.

Answer (score 0):

Using [angular-translate fallback languages](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/08_fallback-languages) will keep your application running, though some strings may not be translated. Otherwise you need to either use machine translation (low-quality but quick turnaround and free) or human translation (professional quality but takes time and money).